# Logic in the Polycule

Tags: logical-deduction, knowledge, logic-grid

<sup>Heavily based on a puzzle from [*Brainteasers and Mindbenders*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0671761994).</sup>

Eve's anniversary with her polycule is tomorrow, and she's bought presents for all of her partners.  However, she stashed the presents in the back of her closet in a whole jumble, and now she doesn't remember which present is for who.  She has four partners (Alice, Bob, Carol, and Dave) and four presents (Ween tickets, an X-Men omnibus, chunky yellow yarn, and a Zelda amiibo).  She racks her mind, and remembers these things:

> **1.** She's giving the Zelda amiibo to a person who's favorite Zelda title is Wind Waker.
>
> **2.** Carol hates Marvel comics.
>
> **3.** The person Eve's giving the Ween tickets to and the person she's giving the X-men omnibus to went on a date to the aquarium last week.
>
> **4.** Alice and Dave don't date each other.
>
> **5.** Dave and Alice have celiac disease...
>
> **6.** ...But that means they never have bread around the house, so Eve doesn't know if Bob or Carol do too.
>
> **7.** Carol and Dave are the only people in the polycule whose favorite Zelda game is Wind Waker.
>
> **8.** The Ween fan in the group can't eat gluten...
>
> **9.** ...but the avid knitter can.
>
> **10.** Eve is giving the yellow yarn to a partner who loves Tears of the Kingdom.
>
> **11.** That's Eve's favorite Zelda game too.

...Well, that was useless!

***Or is it?***

Comment: @newQOpenWid and what, pray tell, is the problem with simple constraint satisfaction problems?

Comment: @Bass in a Puzzling SE swamped with unique and enigmatic problems, they feel slightly out of place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think:

> Alice got the X-Men omnibus
>  Bob got the chunky yellow Yarn
>  Carol got the Ween tickets
>  Dave got the Zelda amiibo

Because:

> First, a couple of assumptions, to make a solution possible:
>
> Eve wants to give people presents she thinks they will like.
>
> Someone who loves Tears of the Kingdom cannot love Wind Waker more.

> Start with the Yarn:
>  The avid knitter can eat gluten (clue 8-9), so isn't Alice or Dave (clue 5).
>  And they love Tears of the Kingdom (clue 10) so aren't Carol or Dave (clue 7).
>  So it must be Bob who gets the Yarn.

> Now for the Zelda amiibo:
>  The Ween tickets and the X-Men omnibus are going to a pair that went on a date (clue 3) so cannot be Alice and Dave (clue 4).
>  So it must be Carol and Alice, or Carol and Dave.
>  And the remaining friend (Alice or Dave) must get the Zelda amiibo.
>  But the amiibo is going to a Wind Waker fan (clue 1), so can only be Carol or Dave (clue 7).
>  So it must be Dave who gets the Zelda amiibo.

> That leaves Alice and Carol with the Ween tickets and the X-Men omnibus.
>  But Carol hates Marvel (clue 2), so must get the Ween tickets.
>  Leaving Alice with the X-Men omnibus.

Comment: is it just me, or is someone set out to downvote both this question and its answers? Because I saw the question getting downvoted almost as soon as it got posted.